# How to pass hardcoded string value from javascript onclick with template option using kendo ui grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am having 2 grids on my page with name **grid1 and grid2**.

Now i want to pass grid name as hardcoded to my 1 common javascript function for deleting records from grid like below:

for Grid 1 delete function:

```
field: "Id",
template:<a  title="delete" onclick="javascript:return Delete(<#=Id#>,<#=grid1#>);" > //showing error in console  grid1 is not defined
```

for Grid 2 delete function:

```
field: "Id",
template:<a  title="delete" onclick="javascript:return Delete(<#=Id#>,<#=grid2#>);" > //showing error in console  grid2 is not defined.
```

My javascript function:

```
function Delete(id, gridname) {
        console.log(id,gridname)
}
```

Comment: if you are providing the names as literal strings then you don't need the `#= property #` just provide the string eg. `Delete(#=id#, 'Grid1');`. On a side note is there a reason why you are creating the delete command rather than using the grid's inbuilt delete command?

Comment: @DavidShorthose:In my grid i have 1 column named "Action".Now in this action column i need to put 2 image named as Edit,delete.So is this possible to put image in command option and with edit option i dont want to perform inline editing or pop up editing.so is this possible?

Comment: So for editing do you want this to navigate to another page/view or do you want it to bind to an edit template outside of the grid but on the same page?

Comment: @DavidShorthose:For editing i want to open my records in edit mode on a new view i.e on new page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. If you write any text between # (hash) the grid try to find that field in your datasource that's why you got the undefined error.

JS Function:

```
function Delete(id, gridname) {
            var grid = $("#" + gridname).data("kendoGrid");
            console.log(id, gridname)
}
```

for Grid 1 delete function:

```
field: "Id",
template: "<a title='delete' onclick='javascript:return Delete(\"#:Id#\",\"grid1\");'></a>",
```

for Grid 2 delete function:

```
field: "Id",
template: "<a title='delete' onclick='javascript:return Delete(\"#:Id#\",\"grid2\");'></a>",
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: You always rock bro.i think you have done phd on kendo ui grid as because u\you only answer most of question on kendo ui grid.

Comment: can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393323/how-to-delegate-telerik-grid-view-common-methods-to-be-call-from-parent-page-fro